# How to Find Out Per key Maximum in scala collection

Tags: scala

Let us consider I hava a collection of eployees as List of Tuples, where t._1 represents department Id, t._2 is salary and t._3 is Name of employee

```
val eployees = List((1, 8000, "Sally"),(1, 9999, "Tom"), (2, 5000, "Pam"), (4, 500, "NK"), (4, 999, "Robert"))
```

Expected Result: `-((2,5000,Kumar), (4,999,Robert), (1,9999,Ashok))`

I am trying with but getting error,

```
val maxSal1 = emps.map(t => (t._1, (t._2, t._3))).groupBy(a => a._1).map(k => {
  k._2.foldLeft(0, "dummy")((aa, bb) => {
    if (aa._1 > bb._1) aa else bb
  })
})
```

Comment: Can you please add to your question by including input, function signature, and then expected output? example: `input: List(1,2,3)`, function signature: `def max(xs: List[Int]): Option[Int]`, `max(List(1,2,3)) === Some(3)`? Also, please consider formatting your code for readability.

Answer (score 4):

Don't overcomplicate things, avoid doing unnecessary operations, and carrying redundant information around. Just be explicit, and spell out the transformations you need at each step. Simplicity is your friend.

`employees.groupBy(_._1).values.map(_.maxBy(_._2))`

Comment: +1. `Map#values` is cleaner than `Map#map` - good point, @Dima.

This simple code would be even more readable, in my opinion, if a case class were used rather than tuple: `employees.groupBy(_.dept).values.map(_.maxBy(_.salary))`.

Answer (score 2):

```
scala> List((1, 8000, "Sally"),(1, 9999, "Tom"), (2, 5000, "Pam"), (4, 500, "NK"), (4, 999, "Robert")).groupBy { 
     |  case (dept, salary, employee) => dept
     | }
res6: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,List[(Int, Int, String)]] = Map(2 -> List((2,5000,Pam)), 4 -> List((4,500,NK), (4,999,Robert)), 1 -> List((1,8000,Sally), (1,9999,Tom)))

scala> res6.map { 
     |  case (dept, employees) => employees.maxBy(_._2)
     | }
res5: scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[(Int, Int, String)] = List((2,5000,Pam), (4,999,Robert), (1,9999,Tom))
```

But note that `maxBy` is a partial function:

```
scala> List[Int]().maxBy(x => x)
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: empty.maxBy
```

As a side note, I'd use `case class Employee` with 3 fields rather than a tuple. I believe it's more readable.

Comment: Why you used `collect` instead of `map`?

Comment: Good point, @Łukasz. That was a mistake. Care to edit for credit? As an aside, I don't always think of `map` in Scala for a `Map` due to Haskell's `fmap` behavior: `fmap (+ 10) $ Data.Map.singleton 10 20` === `fromList [(10,30)]`.

Comment: Scala has `mapValues` for this. To me it is more consistent with other collections to have `map` changing keys as well but that is probably a matter of taste.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with this option and seems to give result,

```
val maxsal1 = emps1.map(t => (t._1, t._2, t._3)).groupBy(_._1).values.map(t => t.foldLeft((0, 1, "dummy"))((aa, bb) => {
      if (aa._2 > bb._2) aa else bb
    }))
```

Output: `List((2,5000,Pam), (4,999,Robert), (1,9999,Tom))`